# Capacitors in series for higher voltage applications

Tags: flyback

From the second circuit below, the red area is a startup network. The App Note states:

[image]

My question is, if I have three capacitors in series because my application reaches 1100V, then the bus voltage is divided by three. Now I don't have a middle point, but two middle points. Is it okay if I connect my startup transistor in the second point, like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if this can be used to "cheat" and get away with a 500v MOSFET on an 1100v bus?  No way... That schematic shows full bus voltage across Q1 (is no Q3), regardless of startup network - the FET *must* be rated for > the max peak bus voltage.  Some of the new [SiC MOSFETS](https://www.wolfspeed.com/power/products/sic-mosfets) are rated for 1700v.

Comment: I'm not asking anything related to Q1, but Q3.

Comment: Looks like it should be OK. Instead of 'mid point', think 'tapping point', of those capacitors. It's a lower voltage than the full rail that's still pretty high.

Comment: @Neil_UK Do you think it can provide enough startup current without overvoltage of some capacitor?

Comment: It can supply a certain instantaneous amount of charge, which will unbalance the capacitors, by an amount you can calculate based on their capacitance. As it's called a 'startup' circuit, it sounds like the demand will be quite short. However, if a continuous current is drawn, then it will unbalance the string of balancing resistors. How much initial charge and continuous current does the startup circuit require?

Comment: @Blue_Electronx there is no Q3 shown in the schematic.